# Google Review: Invalid or incomplete login credentials

Tags: android, google-play-console

Google removed the app from the PlayStore for not including valid credentials for the review.
The problem is that the credentials we include are valid only during the review stage. That is a problem?

Context. By configuration I make the version of the application use the Testing or Production environment. While it is in review, the objective is to use the Testing environment.
This solution is the one we use for Apple without problems. We tried to do the same with Google and it removed the app. In the email sent by Google, a screenshot is shown indicating that it could not log in.

We suspect it was out of the review stage. It's possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what I know the credentials provided should be valid not only in the review stage, but at all times.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).